# about visa entry and exit

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal

im a indian citizen. i am holding a schengen visa through portugal. due to some circumstances i am not visiting portugal now and visiting other schengen countries like Germany and Hungary. would that be a problem at immigration?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the Schengen visa, you can enter and leave the Schengen region from any of the member states. The border guards just ensure than you have all the right documents to be in the region. For Indian citizens, this mostly means the passport, visa and sometimes medical insurance.